# I want to develop GUI to create XACML like WSO2 Identity

Tags: wso2, xacml

Is it possible to develop GUI similar to what WSO2 provides to create XACML.
So we can simplify creation of XACMl policies for admin. This way instead of providing username and password of WSO2 server to our admin/users we can provide internal application pages , so they don't even have to go to WSO2 Identity server to create XACML policies.

Is it possible to get WSO2 IS code and reuse in our application to provide the similar functionality?

Comment: Did you consider using ALFA? The Axiomatics Policy Server? Their UI is business-oriented.

Comment: yes it is possible to write code to do pretty much anything, this is off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All software and documentation produced by WSO2, Inc. or any of its projects or subjects is licensed according to the terms of [Apache License, Version 2](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

This means you can access the code and modify it for your own purpose.

Comment: Thanks David!! In response to your comment above to use ALFA syntax, is it possible to use Axiomatics SDK to only generate XACML policies where policy server can be from any company? Is there any licence or anything req. to use it or it can be used in development like JDK?

Comment: Yes, you do need a license.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much possible and we did the same for our requirement where we developed user friendly UIs to be used to create XACML policies. The end user need not to know about XACML and once the end user provides information related to policy as per design then we called WSO2 IS entitlement policy admin services to create the XACML policies inside WSO2 IS policy server.

So, you may use the Entitlement Policy Admin Service services (SOAP) to create the required XACML policies within your code.
Here is the wsdl url for EntitlementPolicyAdminService in WSO2 IS:

[https://{IS host}:{port}/services/EntitlementPolicyAdminService?wsdl](https://%3Chost%3E:%3Cport%3E/services/EntitlementPolicyAdminService)